# How can I change my evolution once I picked it?

Tags: starcraft-2

I accidentally picked the wrong evolution strain. I replayed the evolution mission, but I wasn't able to pick again. Is there any way to switch the evolution strain? (I really want the Lurker. :D)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While mutations are changeable at any point, evolutions are not.

If you'd like to play through the campaign with the other unit, you will have to reload a save from before you beat the mission for the first time. If that is not available, the only way to swap evolutions is by restarting the campaign.